# How do I configure cloud armor on a website that is hosted on firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-armor

We have a website that is using firebase hosting and is in the same GCP project, only that when entering the GCP console, nothing related to that website is displayed and therefore there is no target to apply in love cloud.

Comment: Cloud Armor requires a Google load balancer.